# Ruby => Javascript translation

Tags: javascript, ruby, deep-copy

curious... how would you write this Ruby in JS?

```
Array.new(3, Array.new(3, 0))
```

which returns

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

i've tried a variety of things but they all seem messy.  i suppose some things just can't be as clean as Ruby, but how would you approach this?

maybe i'll learn a JS trick or two ;)

**EDIT**
It was revealed that this Ruby code does not actually create 3 arrays.  It creates 1 array, that the others reference.  This was not the intention.  I am looking for a way to easily map a 2 dimensional array with X amount of elements, and Y amount of nested elements in JS.

Also... This is a contrived example.  the intension is to be able to substitute 3 with any number.  this was just an example using 3.

Answer (score 4):

You can define it like so:

```
var arr = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]];
```

Essentially you're explicitly defining it. However, this array contains references to three *different* arrays (making a total of 4). To make it behave like ruby, you would need to create a function that mimics this behavior:

```
function arr(size, element) {
   var ret = [];

   for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       ret.push(element);
   }

   return ret;      
}
```

Then you could do:

```
var myArray = arr(3, arr(3, 0)); //myArray contains [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

This is more true to the behavior you see in ruby since each element in the array is a reference to the *same* array (making a total of just *two* arrays). You can verify this by doing `myArray[0][1] = 2;` and then inspecting `myArray`. You should see the second element in each of the arrays in `myArray` set to 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want an empty array container, just to keep track of the length, or to assign values later on, you can do this, a bit hacky but should work:

```
var a = [[,,],[,,],[,,]]

a[1][1] = 'foo'
alert(a[1][1]) //foo
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is valid Javascript syntax, assuming you want to create 4 arrays:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

**EDIT:**

Actually your ruby code only creates TWO arrays.  One array is `[0,0,0]` and the other array contains three references to that array.  If you change `array[0][2]` you also change `array[1][2]`.  Are you sure this is what you want?  The equivalent javascript code would be:

```
var b = [0, 0, 0];
var a = [b, b, b];
```

Comment: Was about to post this. if compressed `[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]` is around same amount of characters than the ruby version.

Comment: Oh i like your edit +1, but you'll have to to set `b = "[0, 0, 0]";`

Comment: John, I'm not sure why you want `b` to be a string.  The OP said nothing about strings.  I did just add semicolons though.

Comment: ah! i did not realize that catch.  that was not my intention.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby you can get the desired effect like this

```
a = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3, 0) }
p a #[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
a[0][0] = 1
p a #[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

In JS like this

```
var multi_dim = function(a, b, value) {
  var myObj = [];
  for (i=0;i<a;i++) {
    myObj[i] = [];
    for (j=0;j<b;j++) {
      myObj[i][j] = value;
    }
  }
  return myObj;
};

var c = multi_dim(3,3,0);
WScript.echo(c); //0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
c[0][0]=1
WScript.echo(c); //1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

replace WScript.echo with document.write if not in windows and/or in a browser

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just do this: http://jsfiddle.net/PZBUr/

```
var i = "[0, 0, 0]";
var myArray = new Array(i, new Array(i, new Array(i)));
document.write(myArray);
​
```

Comment: But that creates nested arrays the first element of each being a _string_.

Comment: Agree, you'd have to use `evil()` or mostly find another solution

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is:

```
var arr = new Array(
    new Array(0, 0, 0),
    new Array(0, 0, 0),
    new Array(0, 0, 0)
);
```

or simply

```
var arr = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
]
```